# How can I convert a MapDB file to other formats?

Tags: mapdb

I'm currently running a [webapp](https://github.com/opentraffic/traffic-engine-app) locally that stores/caches data in [MapDB format](http://www.mapdb.org/doc/getting-started.html). 
I would like to play with the data in PostgreSQL. Do there exist tools to convert the `.db` files to other formats?